# is this grammatically correct or should I rephrase the ODD hour part

Tags: grammar

Also, my new shift is at an odd hour (6PM – 3AM), I need some time to adjust my daily routine accordingly and would not be able to concentrate on the assignments which are a part of the course.

Comment: If you're only asking about the use of *odd*, it's fine. However, the sentence as a whole needs to be punctuated differently. But unless you have a specific question, suggesting a grammatically correct version would be proofreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used ***odd*** perfectly correctly here. It is OED sense 9b of the adjective *odd*. The hours you are describing, in anyone's book can be said to "differ in character from what is ordinary, usual, normal, or expected". They are "out of the ordinary".

9b. Of things: differing in character from what is ordinary, usual, normal, or expected; out of the ordinary; extraordinary, strange, peculiar; unexpected, surprising.

> 1578   T. Churchyard Disc. Queenes Entertainem. sig. Ciijv   Some odde
>   deuice shall meete hir highnesse streight, To make hir smyle, and ease
>   hir burthened brest. 1583   A. Golding tr. J. Calvin Serm. on
>   Deuteronomie lviii. 349   To the end they might not vse any odde
>   shiftes to keepe their naughtinesse from discouering.
>
> a1592   H. Smith Serm. in Wks. (1866) II. 84   Amongst the heathen
>   they had many odd conceits.
>
> 1653   Duchess of Newcastle Poems & Fancies 121   Women writing
>   seldome, makes it seem strange, and what is unusuall, seemes
>   Fantasticall, and what is Fantasticall, seemes odd, and what seemes
>   odd, Ridiculous.
>
> 1679   L. Addison First State Mahumedism sig. Aijv   Though many odde
>   things are here set down of this Imposter, yet they are all own'd by
>   his Sectaries.
>
> 1711   J. Addison Spectator No. 72. ¶2   He was a Member of the
>   Everlasting Club. So very odd a Title raised my Curiosity.
>
> 1712   Lady M. W. Montagu Let. Jan. (1965) I. 114   I have the oddest
>   Jumble of disagreable things in my head that ever plagu'd poor
>   mortals.
>
> 1772   T. Simpson Compl. Vermin-killer i   Some may think it odd for a
>   man to sit down and write on so trifling a subject as vermin.
>
> 1816   J. Austen Emma III. xi. 404   Is this not the oddest news?..
>   Did you ever hear any thing so strange?
>
> 1852   M. R. Mitford in A. G. L'Estrange Life M. R. Mitford (1870)
>   III. xiii. 243   An odd circumstance is that the oak-leaves this year
>   are falling as soon as those of the elm.
>
> 1868   E. A. Freeman Hist. Norman Conquest II. ix. 333 (note)    It is
>   odd that they are not spoken of.
>
> 1908   L. M. Montgomery Anne of Green Gables xiii. 126   The more she
>   talks and the odder the things she says, the more he's delighted
>   evidently.
>
> 1925   V. Woolf Mrs. Dalloway 204   And now there was this odd
>   friendship with Miss Kilman.
>
> 1942   C. Headlam Diary 7 May in S. Ball Parl. & Politics in Age
>   Churchill & Atlee (1999) viii. 311   It is odd how all and sundry
>   appear to be obsessed with the idea that the Russians are going to
>   beat the Germans and then ‘steam roll’ into Berlin.
>
> 1994   A. L. Kennedy Now that you're Back 51   I couldn't say what was
>   wrong about it and we made no fuss at the time, but the atmosphere was
>   odd.

Comment: so you meant to say that the way I use "my new shift is at an odd hour" is grammatically correct

Comment: @Jayanth Yes.....